# The radius of the circle which touches the line $x +y = 0$ at $M(-1,1)$ and cuts the circle $\ x^2+y^2+6x-4y+18=0 $ orthogonally is?

Tags: circles, conic-sections

I had attempted the question using the formula :

$$\ r_1^2 + r_2^2 = d^2 $$

But when I tried to find the radius by the first formula i got the radius as $\sqrt -5$

Then I got confused how can a "complex/imaginary circle" intersect in the real plane with a real circle, that too orthogonally as it made no sense.

Edit: I checked the answer given by plotting it in 3d graph in geogebra and
it seemed to show that the circle intersects. Now the only point of confusion is why?

The answer given was $ x^2 + y^2 + 12x + 4y + 2 = 0 $
[image]

[image]

Comment: You should include your question in the post.

Comment: It makes no sense to me either. There was certainly a typo in the question you received.

Comment: I checked it , no typo

Comment: Are you sure about the formula for the circle in the title? It implies a negative radius, no? perhaps it is $-18$ and not $+18$?

Comment: This was the reason why I got confused as I confirmed it twice and had to leave the question.

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that equation of a circle passing through a point and the tangent to it at that point is given by $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+\lambda(T=0) = 0$ where (a,b) is the point and T=0 is the tangent.

Comment: You can always formally do $((x+1)^2+(y-1)^2) + \lambda (x+y)=0$ with the empty over the reals circle $x^2+y^2+6x-4y+18=0$ then from the relation $2gg'+2ff'=c+c'$ for the circles $x^2+y^2+gx+fy+c=0$ and $x^2+y^2+g'x+f'y+c'=0$ you get $\lambda=10$ and the resulting circle is $x^2+y^2+12x+8y+2=0.$

Comment: I had just one doubt if the circle is not even real how can it intersect a real circle orthogonally

Comment: Another doubt is whether the relation you gave above is valid always even if circle is not real

Comment: I suspect the one who made the exercise just didn't check whether the circle was real.

Comment: Yeah maybe but to be on a safer side can you answer my question whether imaginary circle can intersect a real circle

Comment: Of course, but over the complexes where the algebra naturally lives, and where by Bezout you get four intersection points: the intersection points of $x^2+y^2+6x-4y+18=0$ and $x^2+y^2+12x+8y+2=0$ are $(-(2\sqrt{10}i+8)/3,(\sqrt{10}i+8)/3),((2\sqrt{10}i-8)/3,-(\sqrt{10}i-8)/3))$ and of course the [circular points at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_points_at_infinity) that all circles have in common. And the version of the orthogonality conditions I cited work algebraically over ${\Bbb C}$, if not the concept of orthogonal itself.

Comment: thanks for the answer cleared my doubts

Comment: how did you find the coordinates of intersection

Comment: I found the radical axis $2(3x + 6y - 8)=0$ by subtracting the two equations. The rest amounts to quadratic equations in one variable and backsubstitution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer + 1